# XSLT: Transform XML files tree

Tags: xslt, file, macos, saxon

I have the following file structure (XML files 'index.xml' in nested folders):

```
index.xml
foo/index.xml
foo/sub/index.xml
foo/.../index.xml
bar/.../index.xml
```

Now I have to transform each of this XML files with a given XSL stylesheet. The result should be the same folder structure (overwriting would be OK). What would be your approach to achieve this?

My system: OS X 10.6, Saxon XSLT processor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using Bash**
How about putting the find command in a file and make the file executable:

```
find . -iname "*.xml" -exec transformcommand {} \;
```

(The `{}` will be replaced with the found file.)

**Using Ant** If you want something more platform independent you could write a simple Ant task for it. Have a look at the [Ant XSLT Task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/style.html), which could be combined with the [<for>-tag](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/for.html).

Example:

```
<xslt in="input.xml"
      out="output.txt"
      style="thexsltfile.xsl"
      force="true"
      classPath="lib/saxon9.jar"/>
```