# XSLT transform a set of XML files in a folder and multiple subfolders

Tags: xml, xslt, ant, xslt-2.0

I have a set of xml files in a folder and subfolders that I need to slightly modify by changing the topic title from UPPER CASE to Title Case.

After the change this: FIRST PARAGRAPH OF MY PUBLICATION
should look like: First Paragraph Of My Publication

The folder structure looks like this 
Docs/documents/folder1, 
Docs/documents/folder2, 
Docs/documents/folder3 etc..

I would like to use XSLT in combination with Ant script or any other approach to perform the changes.
Overwriting the source files is ok because I need to keep the same folder structure.

This approach [XSLT: Transform XML files tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765146/xslt-transform-xml-files-tree) is the closest to what I am trying to achieve but I am not able to.

The source XML files look like:

```
<!DOCTYPE topic PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DITA Topic//EN" "topic.dtd">
<topic xmlns:ditaarch="http://dita.oasis-open.org/architecture/2005/" audience="(12-7-1)"
   id="parag128" ditaarch:DITAArchVersion="1.0"
   domains="(topic ui-d) (topic hi-d) (topic pr-d) (topic sw-d)                          (topic ut-d)"
   class="- topic/topic ">

   <title class="- topic/title ">FIRST PARAGRAPH OF MY PUBLICATION</title>

   <body class="- topic/body ">

      <p class="- topic/p ">The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
         The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
         The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.

      </p>

   </body>

</topic>
```

And the resulting XML should be like the below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE topic PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DITA Topic//EN" "topic.dtd">
<topic xmlns:ditaarch="http://dita.oasis-open.org/architecture/2005/" audience="(12-7-1)"
   id="parag128" ditaarch:DITAArchVersion="1.0"
   domains="(topic ui-d) (topic hi-d) (topic pr-d) (topic sw-d)                          (topic ut-d)"
   class="- topic/topic ">

   <title class="- topic/title ">First Paragraph Of My Publication</title>

   <body class="- topic/body ">

      <p class="- topic/p ">The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
         The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
         The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.

      </p>

   </body>

</topic>
```

I have this XSLT

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:param name="files" select="collection('../../*.dita;recurse=yes')"/>

<xsl:template match="topic/title/text()">
    <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="\p{{L}}+">
        <xsl:matching-substring>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(upper-case(substring(.,1,1)), lower-case(substring(.,2)))"/>
        </xsl:matching-substring>
        <xsl:non-matching-substring>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:non-matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>

</xsl:template>
```

from this question [Converting to text to lowercase in nodes and child nodes in xsl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15101862/converting-to-text-to-lowercase-in-nodes-and-child-nodes-in-xsl), but I am not able to make it work on multiple files.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What version of XSLT?

Comment: XSLT 2.0 with Saxon-EE 9.5.1.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `xsl:collection()` in `xsl:parameter`, but you're never using the parameter.

Try doing an `xsl:for-each` over each document in the collection and create the new document with `xsl:result-document`. You can use `document-uri` to get the name of the file.

(**WARNING**: The current example will overwrite the existing file! To test, add an extension to the `href` like `href="{document-uri(current())}.test"`.)

Also, since you're using Saxon-EE, try using the `saxon:discard-document()` extension function. This will remove each document from Saxon's document pool after processing. This will make it available for garbage collection so you don't blow out your memory. (If memory is a concern.)

Example (tested with Saxon-EE 9.4):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="collection('../../?recurse=yes;select=*.dita')/saxon:discard-document(.)" xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/">
            <xsl:result-document href="{document-uri(current())}">
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </xsl:result-document>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="topic/title">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="\p{{L}}+">
                <xsl:matching-substring>
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat(upper-case(substring(.,1,1)), lower-case(substring(.,2)))"/>
                </xsl:matching-substring>
                <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                </xsl:non-matching-substring>
            </xsl:analyze-string>               
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Note**: *The input to this stylesheet would be any XML document. I used the stylesheet itself as input when testing.*

---

Option to ignore text inside parens. (`PUBLICATION HEADING (ABCD)` becomes `Publication Heading (ABCD)`)

```
<xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="\p{{L}}+|\([^\(\)]+\)">
    <xsl:matching-substring>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="matches(.,'^\(')">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="concat(upper-case(substring(.,1,1)), lower-case(substring(.,2)))"/>                           
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:matching-substring>
    <xsl:non-matching-substring>
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:non-matching-substring>
</xsl:analyze-string>
```

This may not be the best/most extensible way, but I only had a few minutes.

Comment: Oops! Sorry @ManUO. I just need to add an `<xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>`. I will update.

Comment: Thanks a million Daniel, is it possible to exclude anything in parentheses inside the title element? Like if I have a title that looks like this: <title class="- topic/title ">PUBLICATION HEADING (ABCD)</title> convert to <title class="- topic/title ">Publication Heading (ABCD)</title>?

Comment: @ManUO - I added an example of a new `xsl:analyze-string`. It might not be the best option, but it was quick. :-)

Comment: Thanks again. I just tried on a sample and it seems to be producing the proper result.

Answer (score 0):

Use your Ant `xslt` task to drive the application of XSLT, so you will have one run of Saxon per file.

Have a source and target directory, so you aren't overwriting anything. During testing, you will be happy you did. Once you are ready to go live, add an extra step to copy everything from the target directory back to the source. Extra points for only copying back if there is a change.

Comment: Thank you so much for the feedback. I tried the Ant XSLT task approach but I keep getting complains about missing DTD for the DITA topic.

Comment: Hmmm. It's possible you have specified an incorrect path for the DTD or schema. In any case, you can download the DTD to your local machine and tell Saxon that it should use those local copies instead.